# How to change the thread priority in linux OS which is built using yocto project?

Tags: pthreads, yocto, glibc

I am using linux os (4.9.126) built with yocto (sumo). It consists of glibc v2.27, util-linux v2.32.1.

The pthread library is located at:

```
ldconfig -p | grep pthread.so
libpthread.so.0 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 3.2.0) => /lib/libpthread.so.0
```

I want to set the priority SCHD_RR inside docker containerized C++ application.

```
..
..
...

    int set_max_thread_priority()
    {
        int policy;
        struct sched_param param {
        };

        pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &policy, &param);
        policy = SCHED_RR;
        param.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(policy);
        return pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), policy, &param);
    }

...
```

I want to achieve

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND 
2083 root      rt   0  709812   8100   6456 S  44.4  0.2   0:32.24 my-application
```

But it shows,

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND 
2083 root      20   0  709812   8100   6456 S  44.4  0.2   0:32.24 my-application
```

When I run docker containerized `my-application` on Ubuntu/Debian, then it works fine.

It does not work with yocto os. When I try to change the thread priority on yocto os (using chrt command) it shows following error.

```
sudo chrt -r -p 99 2083
chrt: failed to set pid 18465's policy: Operation not permitted
```

I am not sure if I am missing any package inside OS.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `cgroups` and create rules for your application's priority.

Comment: Application itself changes its thread priority to SCHED_RR once its is started. I am not sure about what’s blocking (in yocto os) during changing the thread priority. The same application works totally fine on Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Are you using the same kernel? Processor?

Comment: no. ubuntu is running with 5.3.0-42-generic whereas yocto is using 4.9.126